# How to display, on MainActivity, the number inserted on a custom alertDialogFragment with EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I'm using a custom `alertdialog` with an `editText` to insert a number, the `alertdialog` is working, but nothing happens when I click positive button, it should display the value inserted, in `main_activity.xml`.

It seems that my interface is not working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, here is my code:

### TestAlertDialogFragment.java

```java
public class TestAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

// Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events

TestAlertDialogListener mListener;

public interface TestAlertDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, int i, String string);

    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();


    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_dialog, null))

            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    final EditText editText = (EditText) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.number);
                    int i = 0;
                    String string;
                    if (editText != null) {
                        string = editText.getText().toString();
                        i = Integer.parseInt(string);

                    }
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(TestAlertDialogFragment.this, i, string);
                    }
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(TestAlertDialogFragment.this);
                    }
                }
            });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    // makes the soft-keyboard shows when edittext is focused
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

    return dialog;
}
}
```

### MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements TestAlertDialogFragment.TestAlertDialogListener {
int i=0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);


public void showTestAlertDialog(View v) {
    // Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it

    DialogFragment d = new TestAlertDialogFragment();
    d.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "testAlertDialog");
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

}

public void setSelectedNumber(String string, int i) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_number);
    textView.setText(string);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_string);
    String string2 = i;
    textView1.setText(string2);
}


@Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, int i, String string) {
        // User touched the dialog's positive button
        setSelectedNumber(string, i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's negative button

    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Input Number"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="showTestAlertDialog"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test_number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test_string"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

### fragment_alert_dialog.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.datepickertest.InserirPrazoDialogFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="INSERT NUMBER:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#40C4FF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:background="#40C4FF"/>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:ellipsize="middle"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:ems="2"
    android:inputType="number" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are not setting listener `TestAlertDialogListener` in your Activity**. Just make below changes and you will get it working.

Create a constructor in your `TestAlertDialogFragment` which will set the listener for us. I am not pasting the whole code of the dialog, only essential fragments. The `onCreateDialog` method will be as it was.

```java
public class TestAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

// Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events

TestAlertDialogListener mListener;

public TestAlertDialogFragment(TestAlertDialogListener mListener)
{

    this.mListener=mListener;

}

public interface TestAlertDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, int i, String string);

    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}
```

Change your activity code like this:

```java
public void showTestAlertDialog(View v) {
// Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it

DialogFragment d = new TestAlertDialogFragment(MainActivity.this);
d.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "testAlertDialog");
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

}
```

Comment: Althought I got a warning in  TestAlertDialogFragment(TestAlertDialogListener mListener)
 This warning: " Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so it can be instantiated when restoring its activity's state. It is strongly recommended that subclasses do not have other constructors with parameters, since these constructors will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated; instead, arguments can be supplied by the caller with setArguments(Bundle) and later retrieved by the Fragment with getArguments()."

Comment: According to that warning you can define an empty constructor if want.. I will not make any difference in the working of our code..!! Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanx for the explanations. I'm new in this. Liking a lot. Happy code for you too :)