# How to implements listener from Fragment A to Fragment B?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have two Fragment in  one Android Application.

This is the Fragment A:

```
    public class AlertsAgentDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        ...
        ...
        OnDataPass dataPasser;

        public interface OnDataPass{
            public void onDataPass(String data);
        }

        ...
    }

public class AgentClickListener implements View.OnFocusChangeListener {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
                AlertsAgentDialogFragment dialog = AlertsAgentDialogFragment.newInstance(listValueSet_Agent);
                dialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the Fragment B

```
public class AlertsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements AlertsAgentDialogFragment.OnDataPass {
    ...
    ...
    public AlertsDialogFragment() {
        mContext = getActivity();
    }
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public void onDataPass(String data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlertsAgentDialogFragment transaction1 = ((AlertsAgentDialogFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ItemRoleList"));
        transaction1.dataPasser.onDataPass(data);
    }
    ...
}
```

In the Fragment A, the user can select an Items from RecycleListView, I want that, when the user select one item of List, the Fragment B can read this selection.

How can I change my code to do this?

regards

Comment: :Can you please post the code where you load both fragmentA and Fragment B buddy :)

Comment: I have add that code

Comment: you should be calling `onDataPass` in your `AlertsAgentDialogFragment`.. Something like **listner.onDataPass()**.

Comment: Refer this question and My answer. Your code is in Complete , I suppose: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37266958/6127411.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is that you don't have to pass data from one fragment to another, directly.

[As the documentation says](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), you have to pass data from the one Fragment to the Activity, and then the Activity passes those data to the other Fragment.

This is implemented in these three steps:

1. Define an Interface
2. Implement the Interface
3. Deliver a Message to a Fragment

So, I assume you have an `Activity`, that contains the Fragment A and the Fragment B. The idea is to create the interface inside the Fragment A, as you did, and then your `Activity` has to implement that interface:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements AlertsAgentDialogFragment.OnDataPass {
     @Override
    public void onDataPass(String data) {
        FragmentB fragment = (FragmentB)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentB.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if(fragment!=null)
            fragment.setYourString(data);
    }
}
```

Where your FragmentB contains a constant String that represents the TAG

```
public static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "fragment_b_tag";
```

To associate that tag to the FragmentB, when you show that fragment, you need to execute this code:

```
fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), FragmentB.FRAGMENT_TAG);
```

And also your FragmentB need to implement a method (that I called setYourString()) that manages the data passed by the FragmentA.

After that you are done: all the logic for managing the data passed, are in the setYourString() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an events model too, like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) or [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid).

You provide the same Bus for the two fragment. The fragment B will subscribe to an event type that will be posted by the fragment A.

Answer (score 0):

The Communication between two fragments should always happen via it's **Activity**.

Create an Interface and provide it's implementation in your Activity, then when user selects an item in your Fragment A, call the method of the interface with the item in the Activity and then from Activity send that item to the Fragment B.

Something like this...

```
    public class FragmentB extends Fragment{
        public void getItemFromFragA(String item){
            // your code
        }
    }


    public class FragmentA extends Fragment{

        ItemClicked mItemClicked;

        public interface ItemClicked{
            public void sendItem(String item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

            try {
                mItemClicked = (ItemClicked) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
            }
        }

        public void someMethod(){
            mItemClicked.sendItem("Item or Object");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            mItemClicked = null
            super.onDetach();
        }
    }


public class MainActivity implements FragmentA.ItemClicked{
    @Override
    public void sendItem(String item){

        FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_B);
        fragmentB.getItemFromFragA(item);
    }
}
```

Checkout this link for information...

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface

Comment: I can't use activity, because, I have a master activity and I change some fragment.

Comment: your fragments are part of your master activity ryt? implement the interface in the master activity.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are basically controlled from activity.
If you have saved the context of activity in FragmentA you can call the method of that activity from FragmentA which then calls the method of FragmentB.

```
((YourActivity)context).listItemClicked(arg1,arg2,arg3);
```

And then in your activity

```
public void listItemClicked(arg1,arg2,arg3){
    fragmentB.listItemClicked(arg1,arg2,arg3);
}
```

But you need to be sure that fragmentB is initialized and not null.