# Code snippet for creating interface in RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I wish to call a method in my fragment when a button is clicked in RecyclerView adapter ViewHolder.
I found online that the best way to do this is to create interface callbacks.

Please can you show me a code snippet for creating  this interface callback?

---

### My Progress

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    OnButtonClickListener mButtonClickListener = sButtonCallbacks;
    private Context mContext;

    //List of posts
    private List<PostItems> mPostItems;

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 1;

    private int lastPosition = -1;

   public PostAdapter(List<PostItems> postItems, Context context) {
       super();

       //Getting all posts
       this.mPostItems = postItems;
       this.mContext = context;
   }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionItem(position))
            return VIEW_ITEM;
        return VIEW_PROG;
    }

    private boolean isPositionItem(int position) {
       return position != getItemCount()-1;
    }

    public interface OnButtonClickListener {
        public void OnButtonClick ();
    }

    public static OnButtonClickListener sButtonCallbacks = new OnButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnButtonClick() {

        }
    };

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.post_summ, parent, false);
            return new TextViewHolder(v);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_PROG){
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recyclerfooter, parent, false);
            return new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder instanceof TextViewHolder) {

            final PostItems postList = mPostItems.get(position);
            ((TextViewHolder) holder).postBody.setText(Html.fromHtml(postList.getPost_body()));

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).loadButton.setText(R.string.reload);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        //Return the number of items in the data set
        return mPostItems.size();
    }




    public static class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextViewpostBody;

        public TextViewHolder (final View postView) {
            super(postView);
            postBody = (TextView) postView.findViewById(R.id.post_body);
        }

    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements  View.OnClickListener{
        Button loadButton;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        public ProgressViewHolder(View footerView){
            super(footerView);
            loadButton = (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.reload_button);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) footerView.findViewById(R.id.progress_load);

            loadButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            if(NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(footerView.getContext())) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            } else if (!NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(footerView.getContext())) {
                loadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == loadButton.getId()) {
                //I can't access mButtonClickListener from here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am two problems from the link in janki gadhiya's comment.

1. I can't  access mButtonClickListener from the button's onClick.
2. I don't know how to ensure that the host activty implements the interface.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Refer my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37267574/6127411

Comment: @jankigadhiya pls read my question again. I said RecyclerView adapter and fragment.

Comment: @jankigadhiya while I like your insight about the nature of interface implementations, I sincerely don't like your **code for me service ** comment. Am new to Android dev, how on earth could I know that interface implementations is the same everywhere.

Comment: But you should try something first by your self you can refer examples. There is google and SO for that. After trying if you are facing any difficulty then ask.

Comment: @jankigadhiya  I'll try and get back here if it didn't work.

Comment: Refer this this is best for you : https://gist.github.com/butelo/8729891. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: @jankigadhiya I have tried but I ran into problems. I have updated my question with the problems please can you take a look at it?

Comment: Of course.. I am glad you tried.. I will take a look at it and do the need full if I can :)

Comment: @jankigadhiya ok sir

Comment: you got the solution or not??

Comment: @jankigadhiya no sir

Comment: see my answer @Roseyk